# `heroku git clone` is not cloning the last version

Tags: git, heroku, clone

I am trying to clone my app to my laptop by `heroku git:clone -a appname`  this did not retrieve the latest version.

When I did

```
 git log --oneline --graph --decorate -10
```

I didn't see the latest version that I have on Heroku. How can I retrieve the latest version from Heroku?

Answer (score 0):

Whether this works depends on how you have been deploying. [Only `git push` deployments populate the Git repository that you can access via `git clone`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git-clone-heroku-app):

> You **cannot** clone your app’s source from Heroku if you deploy your app with any method besides `git push`. Other deployment methods do not update your app’s Heroku Git repo, causing `heroku git:clone` to return an empty repository.

Do you have a canonical upstream repository, e.g. on GitHub? If so, that is where you should clone from:

> A Heroku app’s Git repository is intended for deployment purposes only. Cloning from this repository is not officially supported as a feature and should be attempted only as a last resort. **Do not** use this repository as your app’s canonical “origin” repository. Instead, use your own Git server or a version control service such as GitHub.

If you have not been deploying via `git push` and you do not have a canonical upstream repository, you must have been deploying via the container registry or one of the more obscure methods like a "Heroku button".

If you used the container registry you should be able to [pull your container down](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli-commands#heroku-container-pull), but depending on how it was built it may not contain your source code. For other methods, you'll have to provide more information.